# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline: How to copy to my VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I created a simple .net core console app. This app's repository is a Azure DevOps one. I have also created a ubuntu vm which i can successfully connect to, to receive the deploy.

I have managed to deploy my app from my local computer, by cloning, building and pushing it (via scp command).

Now I would like to do this using azure devops pipeline?

I managed to build the app, but now i can't seem to find help regarding how to execute the `scp` (or a alternative) command...

**Edit1:**
Ok, this is turning out to be an order of magnitude harder than I expected. I'm giving up for now. I've been trying to figure this out for almost 2 work-days. I can't believe that a task that requires 4-6 commands on a script on my local machine should require this much effort to do on a devops environment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Copy files over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) pipeline task which supports SCP.

Comment: this didn't worked out as expected... i can't make the "SSH Service Connection" dropdown work (i created even an instance of each possible service) and i can't enter the YAML on my release pipeline

Answer (score 5):

You can configure a deploy agent to your VM and use a release management to copy and configure your applications:

1. [Deploy an agent on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops)
2. [Define your multi-stage continuous deployment (CD) pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops)